# Stop Activity bring into front automatically

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an android application. In that have splash and home screen. When i press(splash page) app will go to background but after some time it automatically bring into front with home page. How can i solve this?

Splash

```
Intent in = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
          HomeActivity.class);
          startActivity(in);
          overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_to_top);
          finish();
```

Comment: can u explain a bit more about the problem you are facing ,  how does the app go to background on pressing splash page?

Comment: You have finished it.It can't do what you're saying.I must be another part of your code doing it.

Comment: @Kaveri while app is running with splash page. ath that time if i press home page and open nother application. That time the app is automatically bring into front with home page.means that override another application that i opened

Comment: where is the code for intent written , in handler or any other..?

Comment: in  new Handler().postDelayed

Answer (score 1):

you can use flags like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` Clears the activity stack.

and if you want to start an activity after a certain time period you can do like this:

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){
        public void run() { 
         SplashActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
          }
        });
       }
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: i dont want to show activity after some time.the scenario is app is running with splash page. ath that time if i press home page and open nother application. That time the app is automatically bring into front with home page.means that override another application that i opened. I dont want to bring app into front if i press home button

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this you need to determine if `SplashActivity` has been paused BEFORE starting the `MainActivity`. I assume that your `SplashActivity` is doing some processing before it launches `MainActivity`. You should be able to prevent this by calling `finish()` in `onPause()` if `onPause()` is called BEFORE you start `MainActivity`.